# Why doesn't "make" echo anything?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a strange behavior with my `make` command.

It doesn't print commands lines before executing.
I know the existence of `-s`, `--silent` and `--quiet` options or the usage of `@` before a command line. And I do not use any of them.

For example, a very basic Makefile:

```
all:
        touch toto.txt
        rm toto.txt
```

Execution on my computer:

```
mylogin@debian:~$ make
mylogin@debian:~$
```

Execution on another computer:

```
mylogin@debian:~$ make
touch toto.txt
rm toto.txt
mylogin@debian:~$
```

The version of make is the same on these two computers:

```
mylogin@debian:~$ make -version
GNU Make 3.81
...
```

Printing the command line is the default behavior (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html) and I don't use any special configuration.

Someone know why my `make` execute but doesn't echoing command line?

**PS:**

- I don't have a file or a directory named "all"
- If I remove `rm toto.txt` the file is created without any make's echoing.

**PPS:**

- These are the final lines of output when I issue `make -d`:

  ```
   Considering target file `all'.
    File `all' does not exist.
    Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
   Must remake target `all'.
   Need a job token; we don't have children
   Putting child 0x01144970 (all) PID 7478 on the chain.
   Commands of `all' are being run.
   Live child 0x01144970 (all) PID 7478 
   Reaping winning child 0x01144970 PID 7478 
   Removing child 0x01144970 PID 7478 from chain.
   Considering target file `all'.
   File `all' was considered already.
  ```

Comment: Here is the `make -d` output: http://pastebin.com/kwt41E15. Nothing seems wrong for me.

Comment: I have copied the final lines into your answer. It says it invokes the commands to make the `all` target, but doesn't show them; I think it should. If you want to help some of the readers here, retry with `env LANG=en_US make -d`.

Comment: There is the english version : http://pastebin.com/MXrrA3Kp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this string in your debug output:

> Need a job token; we don't have children

I cannot get this string in debug output unless I'm using the `-j` option. However, you state that you used `make -d` at the command line. That's also what your pastebins show.

This suggests to me that you are not running a stock (i.e. unmodified) GNU make. Possibilities:

- You are in fact running a script that wraps around the real make and passes `-j` and `-s` to make *in addition* to the parameters you give. The addition of `-j` explains the line above. The addition of `-s` explains why you do not get an echo.
- You have a shell alias or a shell function that does the same as the putative script above. (In bash you can use `type -a make` to check what `make` is. Thanks to MadScientist for the reminder about `type -a`.)
- You are using the `MAKEFLAGS` environment variable to set `-j` and `-s`. (In bash you can check it with `printenv MAKEFLAGS`.)
- You are running a custom binary.

Comment: Please run the command `type -a make` to see if your environment has any special alias or shell function that invokes make with extra flags.

Comment: @MadScientist Forgot about that method.

Comment: Nothing use `make` when I do `alias` in my bash.
Same behavior when I run directly `/usr/bin/make`.
Also, I try an `apt-get purge make` and an `apt-get install make` still same behavior.

Comment: @Oneil67  `apt-cache policy make` will tell you where the `make` you install with `apt-get` comes from.

Comment: @Oneil67 I had not thought about `MAKEFLAGS` earlier. Check whether it is set: `printenv MAKEFLAGS`. (The output of the policy check looks fine.)

Comment: Thank you @Louis ! That was the `$MAKEFLAGS` which contain `-s` !

Comment: @Oneil67 Great! And oops... I'm so used to `-q` on other commands that I wrote that in my answer instead of `-s`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a file or directory named `all` in your working directory on your computer.  Make sees that, and sees the rule to create `all` in your makefile, and decides it's up to date (since it exists and has no prerequisites) and so doesn't do anything.

Adding a `.PHONY: all` to your makefile will solve this.  You can also run `make -d` and see what make is thinking (in great detail) when it runs your makefile.

Comment: @Oneil67 adding to the above answer you could remove the `rm toto.txt` rule and check if toto.txt is created after running `make` just to confirm if rules are not executing or make is not echoing

Comment: With make 3.81 and 4.0, running `make` with the Makefile shown by the OP, when there is an `all` file already existing in the current directory will output `make: 'all' is up to date`.

Comment: True.  I thought it might only do that if you run `make all` but not so.  In that case I can't think of any way make would run without printing any output. He'll have to investigate: run `make -d` as I suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
I don't have a file or directory named "all". It is the same result with ".PHONY: all" in the Makefile. Here is the `make -d` http://pastebin.com/kwt41E15 . The commands are run: if I remove `rm toto.txt` the file is created.